# Nested class(static inner) lifetime/scope

Tags: java, nested-class

I declared a Static Inner class, of which I am creating a new instance in a method of Outer class. But, I am getting result suggesting that the same instance of Inner class is used everytime in my method.
Example Below,

```
public class Outer{

   public method m(){
      Inner n = new Inner();  //Creating local instance of Nested class
      n.something();
   }

   public static class Inner{
       Map<K,V> cache = new Map<K,V>();

       void something(){
          //use and update cache;
       }
   }
}

public Test{
   public static void main(String a[]){
     Outer o = new Outer();
      o.m();
      o.m();  //cache was still available
   }
}
```

Can someone help with why two instance of Inner class are not created?
Also, should this behaviour change if I remove `static` from inner class?

Comment: It **does** create two instances in your case. I think there is something wrong with the way you determining that there aren't two instances. Since we don't have the complete code, I can't yet comment about that.

Comment: Adding "static" to the inner class implies that you can instantiate it outside the outer class. Can you elaborate what results you're getting "suggesting that the same instance of Inner class is used everytime in my method" ?

Comment: The quoted code contains syntax errors, so it must be significantly different from anything that compiled. Please post code that reproduces the problem you are having.

Comment: my bad, actually it was the static keyword before the `cache` in my actual code that was "persisting" it. Code written above was extra simplification of my actual code. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score -2):

`static` `inner` classes can be instantiated only once per outer enclosing class instance.Since you have only one `Outer o = new Outer();` outer instance  `o.m();` will call same instance of inner class. 
Create two instances like this

```
Outer o = new Outer();
o.m();
Outer o1 = new Outer();
o1.m();  // will create new instance of inner
```

Regarding `static` key word

Nested classes can be: static and non-static. Nested classes that are declared static are s static nested classes. Non-static nested classes are called inner classes.

A static nested class does not have a reference to a nesting instance, so a static nested class cannot access non-static methods of an instance of the class in which it is nested.

Comment: _"static inner classes can be instantiated only once per outer enclosing class instance"_. This is not right. If that where true, [how does the nested class Entry works](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.Entry)?

Comment: Acknowledged. A static inner class behaves like any ``outer'' class. It may contain methods and fields, and it may be instantiated like this:

Outer.Inner object = new Outer.Inner ();  Thanks for correcting me